# Plotting multiple bars with matplotlib using ax.bar()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

Following up my previous question: [Sorting datetime objects by hour to a pandas dataframe then visualize to histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56041988/sorting-datetime-objects-by-hour-to-a-pandas-dataframe-then-visualize-to-histog)

I need to plot 3 bars for one X-axis value representing viewer counts. Now they show those under one minute and above. I need one showing the overall viewers. I have the Dataframe but I can't seem to make them look right. With just 2 bars I have no problem, it looks just like I would want it with two bars:
[image: I need to plot 3 bars for one X-axis value representing viewer counts.]

The relevant part of the code for this:

```py
# Time and date stamp variables
allviews = int(df['time'].dt.hour.count())
date = str(df['date'][0].date())
hours = df_hist_short.index.tolist()
hours[:] = [str(x) + ':00' for x in hours]
```

The hours variable that I use to represent the X-axis may be problematic, since I convert it to string so I can make the hours look like `23:00` instead of just the pandas index output `23` etc. I have seen examples where people add or subtract values from the X to change the bars position.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
short_viewers = ax.bar(hours, df_hist_short['time'], width=-0.35, align='edge')
long_viewers = ax.bar(hours, df_hist_long['time'], width=0.35, align='edge')
```

Now I set the `align='edge'` and the two width values are absolutes and negatives. But I have no idea how to make it look right with 3 bars. I didn't find any positioning arguments for the bars. Also I have tried to work with the plt.hist() but I couldn't get the same output as with the plt.bar() function.

So as a result I wish to have a 3rd bar on the graph shown above on the left side, a bit wider than the other two.

Comment: "I didn't find any positioning arguments for the bars." - this is because you have complete control over the positions of the bars in the first argument (your `hours`). This seems like a weird hassle compared with something like Excel, until you try and create a bar chart with uneven spacing and unequal bar widths in Excel :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure matplotlib, instead of using the width parameter to position the bars as you've done, you can adjust the x-values for your plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some fake data:
n_series = 3
n_observations = 5
x = np.arange(n_observations)
data = np.random.random((n_observations,n_series))


# Plotting:

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5))

# Determine bar widths
width_cluster = 0.7
width_bar = width_cluster/n_series

for n in range(n_series):
    x_positions = x+(width_bar*n)-width_cluster/2
    ax.bar(x_positions, data[:,n], width_bar, align='edge')
```

[image]

In your particular case, [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) is probably a good option. You should (almost always) try keep your data in [long-form](https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/basics/wide-and-long/) so instead of three separate data frames for short, medium and long, it is much better practice to keep a single data frame and add a column that labels each row as short, medium or long. Use this new column as the `hue` parameter in Seaborn's `barplot`

Comment: Thanks Dan for following up on this question too, much appreciated! I just got into the habit of using pandas for literally everything, I'm working on picking up the syntax so I would come up with solutions in dataframes rather than pure python. :)

Comment: Pandas is great, just don't split your DataFrames unnecessarily. Seaborn works very well with pandas. Lastly, unless you want a lot of control over the look of the charts, there's probably no reason for you to stick with the pure matplotlib method.

Answer (score 5):

`pandas` will do this alignment for you, if you make the bar plot in one step rather than two (or three). Consider this example (adapted from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) to add a third bar for each animal).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

speed = [0.1, 17.5, 40, 48, 52, 69, 88]
lifespan = [2, 8, 70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28]
height = [1, 5, 20, 3, 30, 6, 10]
index = ['snail', 'pig', 'elephant',
         'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': speed,
                   'lifespan': lifespan,
                   'height': height}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in directions! Actually I have tried out with this example from the docs a few times yesterday but now you reassured me that this is the direction, so I pushed a little harder. The problem was obvious, and this simple and pragmatic solution worked after I converted my dataframe slices to lists.